# how to call android activity from standard java code?

Tags: java, android, robotium

This is my sample test project which tests android calculator using robotium.
I want to create jar file of this project but while creating it, it shows error as below:

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class TestMain".
```

I think its showing this error becouse there is no main class in that i.e. it couldn't  find "`public static void main(String args[])`". what should i do to overcome this problem?

```
package com.testcalculator;

import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class TestCal extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
{
    private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID="com.calculator";
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME="com.calculator.Main";
    private static Class launcherActivityClass;
    static
    {
        try
        {
            launcherActivityClass=Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public TestCal()throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        super(launcherActivityClass);
    }

    private Solo solo;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(),getActivity());
    }
    public void testDisplayBlackBox() 
    {
        solo.enterText(0, "10");

        solo.enterText(1, "20");

        solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");

        assertTrue(solo.searchText("200"));
    }
    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception 
    {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on Android? As far as I know Android *doesn't* use `main` method.

Comment: simple answer not possible

Comment: that means its not possible to create jar file of android project?